# How can I create string with number in JAVA

Tags: java, string

I want to to obtain a string with this format:

```
"000xxx"
```

Some example:

```
int xxx = 10  -> result = "000010";
int xxx = 015 -> result = "000015";
int xxx = 100 -> result = "000100";
```

What can I use to format it as a String?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

Comment: First try. If you face problems, then ask a **specific** question, along with the (faulty) code you would have written.

Answer (score 2):

You can use append left with `String.format` for example :

```
int myInt = 1;
String result = String.format("%06d", myInt);
```

**Output**

```
1      000001
10     000010
101    000101
```

Comment: Why did you use a string, if you Integer.parseInt it after anyway :p

Comment: yes, i'm not sure what the OP use like type, thank you any way @Nathan

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Temp {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(StringReturn.numToString(1));
    System.out.println(StringReturn.numToString(10));
    System.out.println(StringReturn.numToString(101));
}}

class StringReturn
{
    static String numToString(int num){
        return String.format("%06d", num);
}}
```

OUTPUT

```
000001
000010
000101
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.format("%06d", n);`, where `n` is an integer, should work fine for your formatting. It appears to be 6 digit width, with leading `0`'s. Like the other answer suggests, if you are simply looking for the String you could just do `String.format("%06d", n);`.

Source:
[Formatting Numeric Print Output](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

Answer (score 0):

this may help;

```
  static String getString(int xxx)
       {
            if(xxx > 0 && xxx < 1000)
                 return String.format("%06d", xxx);
            return null;

        }
```